# Meaning of と思う in this phrase

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Context: Two girls are talking about something that happened to one of them (something started to grow in her back) and her mother told her that it's happening because her father is an angel. Her friend seems not to believe that story and the girl responds this:

絶対噓だと思うよね。わたしも思う

I think she's saying here that, context here, what her mother said was a lie and she also thinks that it was a lie.
Or the と思う is being redundant and she says she thinks that it was a lie.

I don't know if と思う is used for quotation apart from being used to express what you think.

Comment: These two sentences were probably said by two different people. Can you explain the context in detail? How many people are there in this situation?

Comment: I just edited the post, the context should be visible.

Answer (score 4):

Without context, I would think the subject of the first 思う is people in general, like “everyone” or “anyone”.

> 絶対噓だと思うよね。わたしも思う
> Anyone would think it is a lie, right? I think so, too.

Comment: I just edited the post, adding context.

Comment: @AkagamiKuroh - It doesn't change my interpretation.